# Is it fard to recite dua ma’thur ( دعاء مأثور ) before finishing the prayer?

Tags: salat, fiqh

Is it fard to recite dua ma’thur before finishing the prayer? The dua that is recited just before finishing the prayer. I once read it is optional.

Comment: I have no idea what du'a masura is, so it would be helpful to tell us the wording. it is always best to perform the prayer in the way our Prophet pbuh showed us. Note that he even taught us different wordings. But you can say what ever is called a du'a with some specifications in the schools of jurisprudence.

Answer (score 1):

The Dua after the last tashahhud \ durood is a ***sunnah*** and is neither a rukn nor fard according to any of the four schools.

The Dua should be ma'thur (لدعاء المأثور) according to the Hanafis, but that is not necessary according to the others.

**Ref:** [Al-Fiqh ala Al-Madhahib Al-Arbaah](https://archive.org/details/IslamicJurisprudenceAccordingToTheFourSunniSchoolsAlFiqhalaAlMadhahibAlArbaah/page/345/mode/1up?view=theater) [En] , [Fiqh al-Islami wa Adillatuhu](https://shamela.ws/book/384/865) [Ar]